# How to create a rectangle using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Here is sample code for VB. Learning this, however when I run it give me an error code on line 2 that says “end of statement needed” please advise

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim g.DrawRectangle As Integer
    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        Me.Refresh()
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnTetris_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTetris.Click
        Dim penBlack As New Pen(Color.Black, 5)

        g.DrawRectangle(penBlack, 50, 100, 50, 50)
        g.DrawRectangle(penBlack, 100, 100, 50, 50)
        g.DrawRectangle(penBlack, 100, 50, 50, 50)
        g.DrawRectangle(penBlack, 150, 50, 50, 50)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: When you paint a shape on the surface of a control, you need to use the Control's [Paint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint) event. You just need to subscribe to the event (or override OnPaint  in a derived control). The `PaintEventArgs`' `e.Graphics` objects provides the drawing functions, as the `DrawRectangle` method you're trying to use now. **Do not** use `Control.CreateGraphics()` to generate a graphics context when you want to paint shapes. This method is used, mainly, to measure stuff (the size of Text when painted, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
Dim g.DrawRectangle As Integer
```

Does not make any sense. I *think* I understand what you're wanting to do, are you trying to keep the graphics object that is stored elsewhere?

More than likely if you're trying to just draw rectangles on the Form, then get rid of that line and modify your btnTetris's click event to the following:

```
Using g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
    Using penBlack As Pen = New Pen(Color.Black, 5)
        g.DrawRectangle(penBlack, 50, 100, 50, 50)
        g.DrawRectangle(penBlack, 100, 100, 50, 50)
        g.DrawRectangle(penBlack, 100, 50, 50, 50)
        g.DrawRectangle(penBlack, 150, 50, 50, 50)
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

The code on line 2 (`Dim g.DrawRectangle As Integer`) is so problematic that I am not sure where to start.

'Dim' is explained in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/dim-statement; however this does not clearly identify how it not normally used natively within the `Class` scope. In this scope, I would expect `Private` to be used instead (also defined in the above link, so you are `Dim`ming but just using different words).

But a big issue is `g.DrawRectangle` - what is `g` and why are you trying to `Dim` a method within the object `g` which is already defined in the `Class` upon which `g` is based. `g` is an instance of a `Class` but there are no clues in your code what `Class` `g` is supposed to represent.

As such, the compiler is confused.

That you mention "when I run it give me an error code on line 2 " tells me that you are more likely running VBA rather than VB.Net because within a decent IDE (such as Visual Studio) that code would not even compile.